# {$taxonomy}_edit_tags is putting the meta box about title/slug/desc

Tags: wordpress, hook, taxonomy

When I use {$taxonomy}_add_tags() the meta box content appears under title/slug/desc.

When I use {$taxonomy}_edit_tags(), the meta box content appears OVER the title/slug/desc.

Is there something special I need to do when hooking it to make it appear lower on the edit page?

Example calls

```
add_action( 'barcomp_room_add_form_fields', [ $barcomp_settings, 'show_room_taxonomy_meta_boxes' ] );
```

[add_form_fields Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9qwy.png)

```
add_action( 'barcomp_room_edit_form_fields', [ $barcomp_settings, 'show_room_taxonomy_meta_boxes' ] );
```

[edit_form_fields Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHlH3.png)

Example Taxonomy

```
function init_taxonomy_room() {
    register_taxonomy( 'barcomp_room', [ 'barcomp_event', 'barcomp_meeting' ], array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'capabilities' => array(
            'manage_terms'  => 'barcomp_settings', 
            'edit_terms'    => 'barcomp_settings', 
            'delete_terms'  => 'barcomp_settings', 
            'assign_terms'  => 'barcomp_settings'
        ), 
        'labels' => array(
            'name'                  => _x( 'Rooms', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'         => _x( 'Room', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'          =>  __( 'Search Rooms' ),
            'all_items'             => __( 'All Rooms' ),
            'parent_item'           => __( 'Parent Room' ),
            'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Room:' ),
            'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Room' ),
            'update_item'           => __( 'Update Room' ),
            'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Room' ),
            'new_item_name'         => __( 'New Room Name' ),
            'menu_name'             => __( 'Rooms' ),
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug'          => 'barcomp_room'
        ), 
        'show_ui'       => true,
        'show_in_menu'  => false,
        'hierarchical'  => false, 
        'meta_box_cb'   => true,
        )
    );
} // END function init_taxonomy_location()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Since the Add page uses DIVs, and the Edit page uses a table, I cloned and modified an edit version of the callback so that it displays properly.